# Remove a specific element in json dynamically usinf typescript/ javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have below json which has a node careerLevels and this contains inner child elments.

```
input = {
            "careerLevelGroups": [
                {
                    "201801": 58,
                    "201802": 74,
                    "careerLevel": "Analyst",
                    "careerLevels": [
                        {
                            "201801": 29,
                            "201802": 37,
                            "careerID": "10000100"
                        },
                        {

                            "201801": 29,
                            "201802": 37,
                            "careerID": "10000110"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {

                    "201801": 58,
                    "201802": 74,
                    "careerLevel": "Consultant",
                    "careerLevels": [
                        {

                            "201801": 29,
                            "201802": 37,
                            "careerID": "10000080"
                        },
                        {

                            "201801": 29,
                            "201802": 37,
                            "careerID": "10000090"
                        }
                    ]
                }
]}
```

i need to remove all the careerLevels node  **dynamically** from this json and only display below json.

```
output= {
            "careerLevelGroups": [
                {
                    "201801": 58,
                    "201802": 74,
                    "careerLevel": "Analyst"

                },
                {

                    "201801": 58,
                    "201802": 74,
                    "careerLevel": "Consultant"

                }
]}
```

I have tried to use

```
let strippedJson = copyObject(mergedJson);
    delete strippedJson.careerLevels; // remove careerLevels but this is not doing anything.
```

I think i need to use something like :

```
input.forEach(element => {element.delete}) // something like this
```

Comment: I answered, hope it will work as per the expectation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
let output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input));
output.careerLevelGroups.forEach(group => delete group.careerLevels);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array **`Map`** method to iterate the `careerLevelGroups` array and then delete the `careerLevels` property of an object **:**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 "careerLevelGroups": [{
   "201801": 58,
   "201802": 74,
   "careerLevel": "Analyst",
   "careerLevels": [{
     "201801": 29,
     "201802": 37,
     "careerID": "10000100"
    },
    {

     "201801": 29,
     "201802": 37,
     "careerID": "10000110"
    }
   ]
  },
  {

   "201801": 58,
   "201802": 74,
   "careerLevel": "Consultant",
   "careerLevels": [{

     "201801": 29,
     "201802": 37,
     "careerID": "10000080"
    },
    {

     "201801": 29,
     "201802": 37,
     "careerID": "10000090"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
};

var res = jsonObj.careerLevelGroups.map(obj => {
delete obj.careerLevels
return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```